# Python URL encoding with umlauts error

Tags: python, encoding, urllib2

I am reading a webpage content and checking for a word with umlauts. The word is present in the page content. But the python `find('ü')` function is not finding the word.

```
import urllib2
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
page_content = opener.open(url).read() 
page_content.find('ü')
```

I have tried to convert the search string with u'ü'. Then the error is

```
'SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 0'
```

I have used # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- in my .py file.

I have print the page_content. There the umlaut ü is converting to 'ü'. If I try with page_content.find('ü'), it is working fine. Please let me know if there is any better solution for this.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: What editor are you using? When you save the file make sure you save it in UTF-8 encoding (almost all editors have this option). The fact that you use coding: utf-8 at the beginning of the file tells the interpreter you will be using utf-8, but that doesn't make the file utf-8 endcoded unless you make it yourself.

Comment: Check the position of the coding line - it must be first or second line of the file

Comment: @MariaZverina That won't work... Even though he'll won't longer get the error, page_content.find('ü') will always return -1, even though the page does contain ü. As said above, he must save the file saved in UTF-8 in order for things to work. The coding declaration by itself isn't sufficient.

Comment: @IoanAlexandruCucu page_content.find(**u**'ü') should work though ...

Answer (score 2):

Your Python tries to parse the source file (or console input) as UTF-8, but it's actually encoded in Latin-1. You could try to put a

```
# coding: iso-8859-1
```

comment at the top of the source file, or better, use an editor/terminal emulator that supports UTF-8 and save your scripts in that encoding.

Comment: Or even better, you could keep the coding: utf-8 and actually save the file in UTF-8 rather than Latin-1

Answer (score 0):

If you define UTF-8 encoding at the top of the file as follows things should work. Please note that the `coding` line must be either first line, or second line after the hashbang.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import urllib2

url = 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut'
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
page_content = opener.open(url).read() 
page_content.find(u'ü')
```